# Missing drag-and-drop icons in some themes

Tags: theme, icons

I installed a theme (`Materia-Manjaro-Dark-gtk`) on RPi OS 6.1.0. The theme works fine with my app as long as I define the shell variable `GTK_THEME`, but I got the messages "dnd-copy/dnd-none not found" whenever I did drag-and-drop. Same problem with the default theme (`PiXflat`).

The following packages are installed: `pixflat-icons`, `adwaita-icon-theme`, and several other icon themes. Also `gnome-themes-extra`.

`lxappearance` is worthless. I can change the settings to what I want, but when I exit and return the settings are back at their original values. I tried setting the theme to Adwaita to see whether it produced the dnd icons, but changing the theme universally is not possible, not even with a reboot.

I tried `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme Adwaita`. The theme remained stuck on `PiXflat`.

screenfetch says that the theme is `Materia-Manjaro-Dark-gtk`, but the icon theme is `PiXflat`.

I found `dnd-copy` and `dnd-none` in `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/cursors` (but not in `PiXflat`).

I created a `~/.icons/Materia-Manjaro-Dark-gtk` directory and copied `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/cursors` to it. Still no dnd icons.

I put a symbolic link called cursors to `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/cursors` in the same directory. Same problem.

I tried `gtk-update-icon-cache -f -t ~/.icons/Materia-Manjaro-Dark-gtk/`.

What worked:

I copied `dnd-copy` and `dnd-none` from `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/cursors` into `/usr/share/icons/Materia-Manjaro-Dark-gtk/cursors` (the `cursors` folder did not exist).

When I stick the icons in `~/.icons/Materia-Manjaro-Dark-gtk`, it does not work. Basically, putting anything in `~/.themes` or `~/.icons` has no effect.

One problem remains: If I abort a drag, there is no animation of the drag returning to the source. I gather that there is something called a "theme engine". Is it possible that the animation does not work because the theme engine for Materia-Manjaro-Dark-gtk is missing? Is there a way to fix the problem?

Also interesting: If I run the program from my desktop system using ssh -Y, I do get the animation. How is that possible?